# Android App Start Event Listener

Tags: android, events

I am experimenting with Android Studio with event listeners, how can I know when the user starts an(another) app(ie. he clicks open Google Maps) and catch this event while my app service is running? I did some research but no luck with such event listener outside my own app. Is there any way to do it(not tricky)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot receive Broadcasts / Events indicating that other Apps are launched.

You can read the list of Apps that are currently running, and poll this list regularly to see whether there are any new entries.

The user would certainly not appreciate this though, as it will be battery intensive.

An example:

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {
    // process.processName
}
```